# Old UILabel text stays in background

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to change the text of an `UILabel`, but when I set the new text, the old one stays in the background and they are over each other.

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

I tried to set the `UILabel` text nil or "" but its the same result.

```
self.nameLabel.text = ""
self.nameLabel.text = self.user.getFullName()
```

Comment: Provide more context to your code and issue. You seem to have multiple labels.

Comment: You seem to be adding the label to the view again

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks! @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `UILabel` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` so there were multiple labels in it because `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` was called multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

To set label content to " " or nil,

```
self.label.text="";
```

After that you have again written like,

```
self.label.text= self.user.getFullName()
```

value returned from `getFullName()` might be causing problem please update with definition of the same,

Comment: How does this answer the question? You are using the same code in the question.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you provide more context to your code for us to understand more. Anyway, try this solution:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.nameLabel.text = ""
    self.nameLabel.text = self.user.getFullName()
}
```

This should update the UI, if that's what you want.